# How to perform a multi-hash redis query

Tags: redis, nosql

I have multiple hash-keys organized in "folders" like MOC273,

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET MOC273:123654789 "H_W" "json->H_W->123654789" "H_Y" "json->H_Y->123654789"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET MOC273:987654321 "H_W" "json->H_W->987654321" "H_Y" "json->H_Y->987654321"
OK
```

With HGETALL I can get all the data from a hash

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL  MOC273:123654789
1) "H_W"
2) "json->H_W->123654789"
3) "H_Y"
4) "json->H_Y->123654789"
```

How can I get all the hashes contained in MOC273(where the name starts with MOC273) Something like.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL MOC273*
```

**It's possible  ?**

[Current structure of the redis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrnwi.png)

Comment: Well, it's possible to get all the keys that comply with a pattern with the `KEYS` ([documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys)) command. Just read the warnings in that page and think if you really want to have it in production.

Comment: The `KEYS` command brings me all the keys but not the data contained within each of them. I want to perform this action with just one command so it can be performed in atomic time

Answer (score 1):

So you can use Redisearch to create a secondary index around the HASH data structure.  This will allow you to search through HASH data more efficiently.

https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/ - Quick start should help you to get started